# populate s3 bucket information based on user login in Nextcloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, nextcloud

I have multiple s3 buckets for each user of nextcloud which is running on vms separatly allotted to each user. We are converting vm environment to docker on ecs service on AWS. I am trying to populate s3 bucket information based on user sign in so any user connecting to the cluster can access their data in their respected s3 buckets. Please help me how i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create prefixes (or folder) in S3 bucket according to unique identifier of users (e.g. username, uuid, email, etc). Your application needs to be aware of it, and you need to map user sessions to the respective prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

This works, sort of, but it's a bit clunky and not as "transparent" as I'd like it to be.

```
sudo -u nextcloud php occ files_external:create -c datadir=/var/www/nc_external/\$user / local null::null
```